# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in load_workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I use openpyxl operating excel, the code below raises the error. I cannot figure out the the reason.

```
wb=load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\11.xls')
```

Error message:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe  
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data_process.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data_process.py", line 3, in <module>
wb = load_workbook(r'‪C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\11.xls')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 171, in load_workbook
archive = _validate_archive(filename)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 118, in _validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1082, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\11.xls'
```

Comment: If you take a look at the error message you'll see that you have a `\u202a` character in your path.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) about `'\u202a'` char

Comment: Does it work if you use `\\` instead of `/`?

Comment: Try deleting the first letters `r'C:\U` and then re-type them manually.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following,
instead of 1 '\' try using double \

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook(r'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\11.xls')
```

Let me know if this works.